# How to see what was executed in the database via binlogs for specific date?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5, binlog

I am trying figure out how to "query" binlogs to see what was exectued in the database for a specific date. For example, if I execute **mysqlbinlog binlog** then the thing just runs forever and it is had to see what exactly was executed there, especially if binlog is huge. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can give [**mysqlbinlog**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) datetime stamps

Here is a sample datadir folder

```
[root@********* mysql]# ls -l /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.*
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1073742028 Aug 13 03:29 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003111
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 1073741943 Aug 15 13:37 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003112
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql  434864318 Aug 16 16:00 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003113
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql         57 Aug 15 13:37 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.index
```

Suppose you want to see everything executed from 10:45 AM to 2:25 PM on Aug 14th. All of Aug 14th is in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003112`. Run the following:

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2012-08-14 10:45:00" --stop-datetime="2012-08-14 14:25:00" /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003112 > SQL.txt
```

If your range was Aug 13th 5:00PM to Aug 14th 2:00AM, you must span two binary logs. So, you would run the following:

```
mysqlbinlog --start-datetime="2012-08-13 17:00:00" --stop-datetime="2012-08-14 02:00:00" /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003111 /var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.003112 > SQL.txt
```

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

quickest way I'd do it,

mysqlbinlog  | grep 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'

if you are setting the max binlog size to a high value or even not setting it at all (I think the default is 2 GB) then that is why mysqlbinlog takes a while to translate it and that is just how it's gonna be

another reason to make the bin log files huge and take a while to parse, is the replication mode you're using. Row based files are larger.